# Is it a good practice to make ajax call after ajax callback?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am wondering is it a good practice to make an ajax in an ajax callback function (could be called nested ajax calls?) ? Anyway here is my example

ajax.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var string = 'some string';
        $.post('ajax-call.php',
        {
            string: string
        }, function(result) {

            if(result == 'success') {

                // Second ajax call if result returned is success
                $.post('second-ajax.php',
                {
                    variable: 'Some Variable'
                }, function(second_result) {

                    if(second_result == 'yes') {
                        // Do some thing when the second result returned 'yes'
                    } else {
                        // Alert error or something
                    }
                });

            } else {
                // If first result is not success, show a message
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So basically I have two separate php file that is called on different time, if the first ajax call returned 'success' then proceed to call the second ajax call. Or should I be using one ajax call, one php script, and decide what to do depending on the result of callback ? example below.

ajax2.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var string = 'some string';
        $.post('ajax-call.php',
        {
            string: string
        }, function(result) {
            if(result == 'success') {
                // Do something
            } else if(result == 'unsuccessful') {
                // If first result is not success, show a message
            } else {
                // Show error message
            }
        });
    });
});
```

*Note: both php script are quite a heavy and long script which the first script is codes for validating the ajax call, and if everything is validated correctly, proceed to second ajax call to process the datas into database and so on. The first example will make the script much cleaner and neater, but I am wondering if it is good practice to use nested ajax like that ?

All suggestions and comments are greatly welcome. Thank you in advance for enlightening me on this.

Comment: You'd have better to create a server side script which handle all the logic, calling both of your scripts server side. Then you'd have just to make only one request client side handling all relevant data coming from server

Comment: If you need 2 requests, it is cleaner to chain promises, rather than nest Ajax calls. This allows the calls to be reused in many ways, whereas the current situation has hard-wired them together forever :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.
@A.Wolff So you're saying that second script(ajax2.js) is better ?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie what do you mean by chain promises ?

Comment: Ajax() returns a jQuery promise. You can return the promises from 2 helper functions and chain the calls with `.then()`. Much more flexible and easier to maintain than nesting Ajax calls using callbacks.

Comment: @Charas ya that's what i'm saying

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question:

- If both ajax calls are two different services and the second call depends on the first response, I'll do it.
- If they are standalone services, I'll work with promises and do the callback when both are resolved.

Maybe is not focused on the question itself, but I see weird to make two server calls for just one real action (the second one).
What I'll do is to make just one call. If the validation doesn't pass, return the error. If it passes, call the other php on the server side and return a vlid response to the client.
Server should do the same job, but you save one data transmission from client to server.
That's just an opinion. I hope it helped you.